# tried tracking my phone through android device manager. having trouble doing so.help!

Tags: android-device-manager

i lost my s3 a few days back so i tried to locate it using the android device manager. it is showing the date i last used it on but not showing where it was last used. can someone suggest me way to see its last location?
also, i was registered with androidlost even that is not able to show my last location. keeps showing the message "message successfully sent to google who will forward it when it is online".i understand my phone needs to be online for it to show the location but it also says that if its not online my last location will be shown.

Comment: If someone found the phone, removed the SIM card, and performed a factory reset, then I'm pretty sure that AndroidLost and Android Device Manager will both be useless. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: No, I agree. I don't think any of the two services keeps a (publically available) database of "historical locations" (though Google might have such a "secret database", who knows ;)

Comment: true. but the thing is my phone way turned on for a min or two on the same number. so i just want to know what the last location was. plus android device manager shows when my phone was last used can it not show where it was used last?

Comment: If location services were disabled on your phone, then the answer is most likely "no".

Answer (score -1):

I think that you can use *Google* instead of *Android Device Manager* in your particular case. Today it happened to me the very same thing that happened to you and as in your case *Android Device Manager* was of no use. But I typed `find my phone` in *Google* and it gave me map centered around the place where I had actually forgotten my phone. It seems the map cannot be zoomed in, but at least it can give you an hint about where the phone was before discharge.

Here's a screenshot of what I got from *Google*.

[image]

Better than nothing I suppose.

Comment: The "find my phone" Google search uses the same underlying engine as Android Device Manager.